# Input field extends on Mozilla Firefox

Tags: css, browser

I have been testing my website on different web browsers, including Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, Opera, IE 11 and Edge . I noticed that on Mozilla Firefox and IE 11 the input field has been extended for 2px.
Is there a way to fix it?

```css
input[type="text"],
input[type="password"] {
  background: #f0f0f0;
  height: 36px;
  width: 238px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  outline: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Lato-Regular;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: #bfbfbf;
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <input type="text" placeholder="username">
  <input type="password" placeholder="password">
  <input type="submit" value=" ">
</form>
```

On Google Chrome, Opera and Edge it looks like this:

[image]

But on Mozilla Firefox and IE11 it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: We need more context, particularly if you're using Quirks mode.

Comment: By the way, testing on different web browsers is good. I'm not sure where the downvote comes from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `box-sizing: border-box` to your `input`s:

```css
input[type="text"],
input[type="password"] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  height: 36px;
  width: 238px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  outline: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Lato-Regular;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: #bfbfbf;
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <input type="text" placeholder="username">
  <input type="password" placeholder="password">
  <input type="submit" value=" ">
</form>
```